# can't collect href within a div using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie trying to **scrape** this website using bs4, by collecting href from the specified div and then navigating through product pages by hrefs and collect the data , but I'm stuck at collecting the href .
I would  be extremely happy if someone helped me over this :

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlpage = 'https://www.digikala.com/search/category-tire/' 
print(urlpage)

# scrape the webpage using beautifulsoup

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# find product items
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'c-product-box__title'})
print('BeautifulSoup - Number of results', len(results))
```

here is the first result although when you print results it will come with 36 divs, I just copied the first one, I tried my best not to ask and find the answer but I didn't even come close, so I'm sorry if it's so simple.

```html
<div class="c-product-box__title"><a href="/product/dkp-539563/لاستیک-خودرو-میشلن-مدل-primacy-3-سایز-20555r16-دو-حلقه" target="_blank">لاستیک خودرو میشلن مدل Primacy 3 سایز 205/55R16 - دو حلقه</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class and a type selector combined with child combinator to get the child `a` tags of the divs (specifying the divs by class selector). In this case 36 so no need to limit the children returned.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://www.digikala.com/search/category-tire/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('.c-product-box__title > a')]
print(len(links))
print(links[0])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help , i was wondering which answer is a better approach and why?

Comment: This method should be faster btw as it uses css selectors. I would expect optimization in favour of this. Also, I would prefer a list comprehension as above over a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
html_doc = '<div class="c-product-box__title"><a href="/product/dkp-539563/ﻼﺴﺗیک-ﺥﻭﺩﺭﻭ-ﻡیﺶﻠﻧ-ﻡﺪﻟ-primacy-3-ﺱﺍیﺯ-20555r16-ﺩﻭ-ﺢﻠﻘﻫ" target="_blank">ﻼﺴﺗیک ﺥﻭﺩﺭﻭ ﻡیﺶﻠﻧ ﻡﺪﻟ Primacy 3 ﺱﺍیﺯ 205/55R16 - ﺩﻭ ﺢﻠﻘﻫ</a></div>"'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='c-product-box__title'):
  print div.a['href']
```

Output:

```sh
$ python a.py
/product/dkp-539563/لاستیک-خودرو-میشلن-مدل-primacy-3-سایز-20555r16-دو-حلقه
```

See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: thanks a lot man , this worked too but i'm thinking which method should i use between yours and QHar's answer, btw last line should be   print (div.a['href'])

Comment: The `print` is different on Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

For each resulting `div`, first get the child `a` element, then get the value of its `href` attribute like this:

```
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'c-product-box__title'})
print('BeautifulSoup - Number of results', len(results))

links = []
for result in results:
    links.append(result.a['href'])

print(links)
```

This results in a list of 36 links. Here's a sample of the first 2:

```
['/product/dkp-539563/لاستیک-خودرو-میشلن-مدل-primacy-3-سایز-20555r16-دو-حلقه',
'/product/dkp-959932/لاستیک-خودرو-گلدستون-مدل-2020-2000-سایز-1856514-دو-حلقه-مناسب-برای-انواع-رینگ-14',
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works , is there a reason that i should use this answer over the other ones?